# I want to design a precise digital clock

Tags: oscillator, crystal

For that I need a 1 hz stable clock with 3 SPY. Which oscillator should I use? Crystal Oscillator or RC oscillators?

Comment: Did you make even a little general research about this subject before asking here? You are asking this first basic question, RC or crystal... if you want precision, the correct answer is very easy to find.

Comment: You are out of your depth if you need to ask that very basic question.

Comment: That is not how typically clocks are built. They use higher speed oscillators that roll over nicely with a binary number. 32.768kHz is a typical frequency.

Comment: Use RTC chip. And there's no 1 Hz oscillator. For clock 32kHz oscillator is generally used.

Comment: Or use microcontroller having RTC

Comment: And if you want precise, research [Rubidium Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubidium_standard) and if accuracy is more important than money, Caesium Standard.

Comment: https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/clocks-frequency-references/3824-chip-scale-atomic-clock-csac

Comment: Can sombody explain if 3 SPY is a common term?

Comment: I'm guessing it means "Seconds per Year". Guessing, mind.

Comment: Using the PPS output from a cheap GPS would give you 0.000000 seconds per year (all decimal digits significant)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a poorly-disguised homework question with zero effort

Answer (score 7):

RC are very vague, not stable enough to be used as a clock. The resistors often have a tolerance of +/-5%, capacitors are +/-10% or +/-20%. While you can get more precise components, they go up in price and at no point do get precise enough for the clock to stay accurate. They are also extremely sensitive to thermal changes, so the value will go all over the place.

Crystal oscillators are a lot better; easily getting to 10 parts per million accuracy. Thermally they are a lot more stable. That is why crystals are almost always recommended for the real-time-clocks in circuits.

Silicon oscillators are another option; tend to be more expensive but are more stable and are readily available.

But you're asking for a 1Hz signal. You won't get that low frequency as standard. You will need to get something faster and bring the clock speed down. But if you're doing that, what's wrong with buying a standard RTC chip (which may or may not come with built in crystal). That option will also save money and power (a decent RTC can run in micro-amp range).

Comment: You're not wrong in your general conclusion, but modern RC oscillators as found on-chip in modern MCUs are substantially more accurate than the discrete ones you are describing.  Still not suitable for a wall clock of course, but they work with types of communication where they didn't use to.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement is 100 parts per *billion*, or 1 x 10^-7.  That is way beyond the accuracy/precision/drift of an uncorrected crystal oscillator.

An oven-controlled crystal oscillator (OCXO) module typically is used for this accuracy/stability range.  They are approx. $50 at Digi-Key.  Note that while the stability is within your requirements, the initial accuracy probably is not.

Another alternative is a GPS receiver module.  These require an antenna and a location with good GPS reception, but you get atomic clock accuracy (1 x 10^-10 or better).  Adafruit has one for around $30.

Comment: Or you could *combine* the OCXO and GPS for a GPS-disciplined oscillator.

Comment: Digi-Key et.al - over $1000.  The better ones cost as much as a rubidium standard.

Comment: Not all — there's a way-more-than-good-enough-for-this-application GPSDO, in a small form factor, that goes for 100 GBP (~$130 currently).

Comment: It also matters what the time is *for*.  A hyper accurate stand alone clock is great for timing experiments, but it's not going to agree with other people's clocks unless there's a path to inform it about leap seconds, which are something inserted from time to time by agreement between human decision makers in a way which cannot be predicted in isolation.

Comment: Regarding cost, there are also temperature-compensated crystal and mems devices, which may be fine for GPSDO when temperature changes relatively slowly with time. And roll your own, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Get a cheap cell phone (or a cell data module) and extract the time from that. Use this to correct local time from a crystal. This has both the required accuracy and stability. Others have mentioned GPS, which is ok as long as you can get signal.

Another option: WWV receiver (USA). Remarkably cheap, but only works if you get signal (and you live in a locale that broadcasts it.)

Here's a list of broadcast-time receivers NIST has identified. https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/radio-stations/wwv/manufacturers-time-and-frequency-receivers There are various types shown that use traceable sources (WWV, GPS, etc) to correct local time.

A device with internet access can use a network time server (using nntp) to correct its local oscillator-derived time. That’s literally zero cost.

Otherwise, using RC or a non-stabilized crystal isn't going to be adequate.

Comment: Interesting question: can you get time from a mobile data module without an active service plan?  If so, that's clever !   But also beware a lot of the cheap ones are 2g which is being deprecated in many places now.

Comment: Yes, on reconsidering that this is an issue. There would be recurring data plan costs for a cell module, which could be negotiated for a large deployment but still nonzero. I added the idea of using network time to leverage an existing connection (nntp) which also implies a data connection.

Comment: When I did set-top boxes (DVRs) they migrated from an RTC to using nntp.